# Email verification for iOS app using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was thinking of making an **iOS** app using **Firebase**, and i wanted to know how to **verify users email** id who sign up for my iOS app? So that only those users who emails are verified can be users of my iOS application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the sendEmailVerificationWithCompletion: method to send the verification email and when a user is logged in you can use the emailVerified property to check the verification stat, as it is defined here...

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user#instance-method-summary

So you can decide what actions can an unverified user do like request the verification again...

Comment: thank you so much for pointing that out, i just skimmed it through, looks like they have a nifty property called **emailVerified** but can it help, like if the user is not verified, he cannot sign in my iOS app?

Comment: You need to handle it yourself, since the user will be logged in....you need to get the currentUser and check if it is verified , if it is verified you can consider the user logged in in your app flow, you can show a message saying verify your email to continue and disable stuff

Comment: Thank you so much @Ymmanuel... So correct me if am wrong buddy,as per my understanding, it is like Firebase will create the account no matter what, but it is upto us programmer, what should be seen to the user or not, i guess using the firebase property of **emailVerified**  i can only then segue to other controllers of the app, else if not verified, throw the alert to user to verify his email to use the app.

Comment: And How Can I verify the email? How to change the value isEmailVerified from firebase?

Comment: with the latest version of firebase you can do that either with a backend server using the admin-firebase node module with the update user method  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users or you can do it  client side with the user verification mail like it is explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

**In my app I did like this**

```
        [[FIRAuth auth] signInWithEmail:emailTxt.text
                               password:pwdStr
                             completion:^(FIRUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                 // ...
                                 NSLog(@"User: %@\nUserEmail:%@\nError:%@",user.uid,user.email,error);
                                 NSLog(user.isEmailVerified ? @"Verified = Yes" : @"Verified = No");
                                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:user.uid forKey:@"userid"];


                                 if(error == nil){
                                     if (user.isEmailVerified) {


                                         self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
                                         NSString *userID = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser.uid;


                                         [[_ref child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/user/%@",userID]] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

                                             // Get user value
                                             NSLog(@"%@",snapshot.value);
                                             // ...



                                         } withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                                             NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
                                         }];


                             }];
```